# About the environment variable access in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have the below Environment variable in Linux machine.

```
$echo $JAVA_OPTS

-Dspring.datasource.username=root -Dspring.datasource.password=XXXX! -Dspring.profiles.active=aws
```

Now I need to pass the password from this environment variable to the Spring Boot application.properties file.

Also,use the access key and secret key in my AmazonClient file.
Can some one let me know how it could be achieved?

Comment: Thise variables should automatically overwrite values of the application.properties

Comment: There is a problem somewhere with your build setup, because your environment variable is meant to be passed directly to your Java VM, not to your `application.properties` file.